# Print password confirm field in user register template file

Tags: theming, forms

I'm trying to theme the user registration form in Drupal 8.
I have defined a custom template for user registration form and printing the fields with the following code.

```
{{ form.field_profile_title }}
{{ form.field_profile_first_name }}
{{ form.account.mail }}
```

When I try to print confirm password field it's not printing the field.

```
{{ form.account.pass}}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can always debug your twig template by printing the present variables, with help of of the [Kint](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module (part of Devel) for example:

```
{{ kint(form.account.pass) }}
```

Or you can also print all of them:

```
{{ dump() }}
```

Further information on this [page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates).